# Is there an English term for "L'esprit de l'escalier"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

*[L'esprit de l'escalier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier)* or *l'esprit d'escalier* (literally, *staircase wit*) is a French term that describes the predicament of thinking of the perfect comeback too late.

Merriam-Webster dictionary defines it as follows:

> Definition:
>
> A witty remark thought of too late, on the way home; the clever
>   comment you wish you had delivered
>
> Example:
>
> "When he bragged about sleeping like a baby, I should have added the
>   bit about waking up crying every two hours, but that's just esprit de
>   l'escalier. At the time I just nodded and said nothing."

Is there an English term for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

English speakers sometimes call this **[escalator wit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier#Similar_English_terms)**.

**Afterwit** can also be a synonym for this concept, with forewit as its antonym.

Definition of *afterwit* in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/afterwit):

> 1. Wisdom which comes after the event.
>
>    After-wits are dearly bought, Let thy fore-wit guide thy thought. ―
>      Southwell.
>      There is no recalling what’s gone and past; so that
>      afterwit comes too late, when the mischief is done. — L’Estrange
> 2. The lack of forethought.
>
>    This week I am fearing afterwit as I create the outline for my next
>      novel ... — Grace Tierney, 2010
>      One good forewit is worth two
>      afterwits. — Saying/Proverb
> 3. A good comeback one thinks of after leaving a social gathering.

Comment: I've never heard the term *escalator wit*, and it seems to me a (possibly deliberately) bad translation of *esprit d'escalier*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=escalator+wit%2Cstaircase+wit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstaircase%20wit%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor M&W report it as such http://www.merriam-webster.com/top-ten-lists/top-10-words-for-intriguing-concepts/esprit-de-l'escalier.html

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: No matter what M&W say, [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=esprit+de+l%27escalier%2Cstaircase+wit%2Cescalator+wit%2C+afterwit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cesprit%20de%20l%27%20escalier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaircase%20wit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafterwit%3B%2Cc0) shows that English speakers don't use *escalator wit* much at all. It's either *staircase wit*, *afterwit*, or the original French *l'esprit de l'escalier*.

Answer (score 13):

I've only ever known it in its literal translation as *staircase wit*.

Comment: I agree. If there *was* a generally-known English equivalent, I think OP might reasonably assume a dictionary would have included it in their definition of the French term. Come to that, if we had our own equivalent we probably wouldn't use the French version anyway, so it wouldn't be in our dictionaries in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

***"20/20 hindsight"*** is a common expression that can be used for your scenario - meaning that [hindsight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hindsight) has perfect vision (20/20 vision) because you have the luxury of time to remember or formulate a better response

> **Definition of 20/20 hindsight from TheFreeDictionary.com:**
>   "Perfect understanding of an event after it has happened; - a term
>   usually used with sarcasm in response to criticism of one's decision,
>   implying that the critic is unfairly judging the wisdom of the
>   decision in light of information that was not available when the
>   decision was made."

---

> "When he bragged about sleeping like a baby, I should have added the bit about waking up crying every two hours, but that's just ***"20/20 hindsight"***.   At the time I just nodded and said nothing."

*Edited to add definition of expression "20/20 hindsight"*

Answer (score 3):

The English term is "l'esprit d'escalier", because English is not ashamed of stealing useful phrases from any language careless enough to leave them lying around.

Answer (score 2):

**Carriage wit.** As in, the situation in which you've left the soirée and mounted your carriage for the ride home and the perfect response occurs to you, only to be wasted on your footman.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this, some place where it has been used or a dictionary entry?