# Are there any words/phrases/idioms like "regret," but more specific?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

The other day I struck up a conversation, about economics of all thing, with a stranger whose political beliefs were quite different from my own. It was a little bit of a teaching opportunity as I introduced him to some new concepts. And while the conversation was respectful and engaging, I kept going over it in my head afterwards, wishing I had phrased certain things in a different way, wishing I had mentioned certain ideas and excluded others, and generally feeling like I did a really poor job of presenting my arguments. Now, I certainly feel better prepared if a similar situation were to arise again. But I had trouble shaking the feelings of "I wish I would have said that..."

Certainly I can refer to these feelings as *regret*. But I'm wondering if there's a word or idiom in usage that's more specific to this type of scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for something I should have said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415723/word-for-something-i-should-have-said)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's ***[l'esprit de l'escalier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier)*** ("staircase wit"), which Wikipedia describes as "the predicament of thinking of the perfect reply too late".

Comment: My thoughts exactly! I was just scrolling down to the "Your Answer" section to post this myself, and here it is! I can't help feeling it's a bit ironic that non-native Anglophones come to ***English** Language & Usage* looking for a word or expression with this meaning, but the best we can offer is ***a French expression***. To my mind, "staircase wit" is a sad reflection of the fact that we couldn't think of any better way of expressing it, so a crap literal translation is all we have by way of comparison / competition! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was thinking the same. Departee maybe: repartee+departure?

Comment: The OP is talking about much more than a *bon mot*.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Haha! I tend to be a bit dismissive of puns (["the lowest form of wit"?](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-primary-source-quote-pun-lowest-tipe-wit-how-60401)), but that one tickled my fancy! Now all I need to know is that French term for *"witty r/departee that I must write down and remember while I look out for an opportunity to dazzle everyone with my wit"* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but at least there *is* an English equivalent, even if it's just a literal translation. I'm still looking for a witty, understandable translation for [küszöbgörcs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30115/is-there-an-english-phrase-for-an-inability-to-actually-leave-already).

Comment: Treppenwitz is another term with the same meaning.

Comment: Related: [Fridge Logic](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic) Warning: TVTropes link. ;)

Comment: "L'esprit d'escalier" is better than "l'esprit de l'escalier", the latter being "wit of the staircase" rather than "staircase wit".

Answer (score 5):

**After the fact**

As an example

> I only though of a good explanation **after the fact.**

After the fact generally means the information is too late to be of use.  It's generally used to express a wish you did or said something differently, but it's too late now.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly ***Afterwit***:

1. Wisdom which comes after the event.
2. A good comeback, retort one thinks of only after the end of discussion or after leaving a social gathering.
   Synonyms: l'esprit de l'escalier, staircase wit, (neologism) retrotort

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/afterwit

Answer (score 2):

The word you may be looking for is **hindsight**, which refers to thinking more about a situation you were in previously. You may in particular be looking for the idiom **"hindsight is 20/20"**, which refers to the feeling that you now better understand a prior situation and know what you should have done differently.

The idiom is derived from the facetious idea of hindsight as a kind of vision, which it isn't really, and the fact that 20/20 vision is considered to be perfect--hindsight is perfect vision, and you always know what you should have done after it's too late.

Answer (score 2):

> [***perseverate***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/perseverate?locale=en) - Repeat or prolong an action, thought, or utterance after the stimulus that prompted it has ceased.

Nice, because you can call your condition *perserveration.*

That said, *perseveration* is often more pathological.   But I've heard it as a synonym of sorts for *stew over*, or

> [***dwell on/upon***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dwelling+upon) - to think, speak, or write about at length or with persistence; linger over.

... those just don't turn into nouns quite as well.