# That moment when you think about a smarter reply that you could've given?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I remember reading this word or expression in a book that describes the feeling you have when you think about a reply that you could've given to someone, but you do it too late.

Comment: Are you looking for something like “in retrospect”?

Comment: I think "normal" is the correct adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for may be [*l'esprit de l'escalier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier), or *staircase wit*. Both the original French and the English translation are used in English.

The phrase comes from thinking of the perfect reply to somebody at the bottom of the stairs, just when you are leaving their house, when it is too late to use it.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109763/is-there-an-english-term-for-lesprit-de-lescalier

Comment: I believe it was Freud who first called them *Stair-step thoughts*

Comment: @Elliot: I believe Freud's *stair-step thoughts* are a different (and arguably better) translation of *l'esprit de l'escalier*. But Diderot came up with the phrase a century before Freud did.

Comment: @Peter; Thank you for pointing that out. It's interesting that you think that. Tell me more about your mother.